# Enhanced Dictation only works in English

Tags: macos, voice-dictation, language

I'm trying to use dictation in Spanish (Yosemite v10.10.5) but it's not writing any text.

I have downloaded the Spanish Enhanced Dictation bundle, deleted and re-downloaded it, deleted it by hand from `/System/Library/Speech/Recognizers/SpeechRecognitionCoreLanguages` and purged the file cache using `sudo purge` with no luck.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

*(I spoke something to the microphone)*
But when I do the same using English:

[image]

What can I do to enable dictation in Spanish (or any other language)? Does it have to do with the OS language?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have updated to El Capitan and the error is gone. It looks like a localization file was corrupt.

So, it seems that the solution is "Reinstall or upgrade your OS"